# Ideas on how automatically to delete credit card details from a database T-SQL backup

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I've been working on a new database which is used by call-centre agents to make sales on various products. During the day, these agents will accept credit card details and store them temporarily before processing. At night, the database is backed up, but we can't backup the credit card details for obvious security reasons. At first I thought just to UPDATE the credit card fields to NULL before backing up using the standard BACKUP procedure, but it turns out that the details need to be kept in the original database, in case they haven't been processed that day. All the sensitive credit card details are contained in one column of one table. This should be straightforward, but I'm a newcomer (this week) to both databases and T-SQL -- any hints or directions much appreciated.

**EDIT: additional requirement**

A requirement of any solution is that it not modify the structure of the primary database. This means that changing credit card ids in the customer details table to a creditcardid keyed to a credit card table, which could then be excluded from the backup, is unfortunately not an option.

Comment: You need to look at encrypting them. What edition of SQL Server? If Enterprise look at TDE.

Comment: They're already encrypted in the database, I should have said. But I still don't want to back them up.

Comment: A common solution; put the PCI sensitive tables in their own filegroup then use filegroup backups to ignore it; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191539.aspx

Comment: "in case they haven't been processed that day" - and what if, in the meantime, the primary database fails? That is, after all, the purpose of taking backups, isn't it? So you restore the database and you don't have the CC numbers. It sounds like conflicting requirements.

Comment: "in case they haven't been processed that day" -- yes, if the primary database fails, we would have to return to the customers and ask for their credit card details again.

Comment: Putting the sensitive tables in their own filegroup wouldn't work, because we want the data contained in the tables -- customer name, telephone etc. -- everything, that is, except the values of the credit card fields.

Comment: Currently, the only thing I can think of is making a temporary copy of the whole database, updating the credit card fields to null in that, and then backing that copy up; but this is obviously not an ideal solution.

Comment: Replace the card details in the details table with cardID -> tblCards ?

Comment: Thanks -- I thought of that, which would work much better than the mass copy, but have been told we can't alter the structure of the database at this stage (going live soon). I'll add that as a requirement in the original question.

Comment: Would they let you create a view with the same name as the table that splits the table?  That changes the internal structure but not the external.  Why go live with a structure that has maintenance problems?

Answer (score 0):

First of all.  You cannot alter the contents of a backup (by design).  Your only reasonable options are a) prepare (alter) the data before it is backed up or  b) Back up everything except for the CC numbers or c) restore the backup, remove the CC numbers and make another backup.

Under these circumstances, I have used the following process: 1. Make/maintain a duplicate/copy of the database (frequently synchronized via ETL/SSIS or backup/restore or log shipping or replication) as a buffer for your backup. 2. wipe the CC numbers from the buffer/copy.  3. backup.

For my synch process, I prefer ETL/SSIS because it gives me more control (and no pausing, like in replication and log-shipping).  However, ETL/SSIS requires much more effort to set up.  Backup/restore is quickest/simplest.

Sorry my solution sounds cumbersome. This is just how I learned to handle this type of scenario.